# Flask SQLAlchemy One to Many Relationship Query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

Cart item is a product added to cart.

When a product is added to cart, i would expect an alert, eg CartItem ID: 1 is added to cart. If the same product is added again, i should get an alert CartItem ID: 1 is already in cart.

Now, when i added the same product to cart, i get a 500 error. How should i query cart_item?

**models.py**

```
...
class Cart(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cart'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    cart_items = db.relationship('CartItem', 
        foreign_keys='CartItem.cart_id', backref='cart', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Cart {}>'.format(self.user_id)


class CartItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cart_item'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.relationship('Product', backref=db.backref('cart_item', uselist=False)) 
    cart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cart.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CartItem {}>'.format(self.product_id)
...
```

**routes.py**

```
...
@cart_blueprint.route('/add_item/<int:product_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_item(product_id):
    product = Product.query.get_or_404(product_id)
    cart_id = current_user.id
    cart = Cart.query.get(int(cart_id))
    cart_item = {}
    
    if any(product.id==cart_item.product_id for cart_item in cart.cart_items):
        cart_item = CartItem.query.join(CartItem.product).filter(Product.id==cart_item.product_id).first()
        flash(f'CartItem ID: {cart_item.id} already in cart')
...
```

*Traceback Error*

> cart_item =
> CartItem.query.join(CartItem.product).filter(Product.id==cart_item.product_id).first()
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'product_id'

Comment: Please provide the **full** error traceback.

Comment: `cart_item` is a list: `cart_item = []`, so you get the `AttributeError` when you try to use it's `id` in the query: `filter(items.c.cart_item_id==cart_item.id)`.

Comment: You are using an association table ("items") which creates a many-to-many relationship between Cart and CartItem. That doesn't make sense. Each CartItem will only belong to one Cart object so you want a one-to-many relationship between Cart and CartItem.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for pointing out my mistake with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for pointing out my mistake for assigning cart_item as a list.

Comment: @GreyLi Thanks for looking at my code. My mistake was at how i defined the relationship between Cart and CartItem. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers, guys. I resolved querying cart_item using self-referential One to Many relationship between the Cart and CartItem.

models.py

```
...
from app import db

class Cart(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cart'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    cart_items = db.relationship('CartItem', 
        foreign_keys='CartItem.cart_id', backref='cart', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Cart {}>'.format(self.user_id)


class CartItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cart_item'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.relationship('Product', backref=db.backref('cart_item', uselist=False)) 
    cart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cart.id'))
    # 'cart' property defined in Cart.cart_items via backref.

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CartItem {}>'.format(self.product_id)
...
```

routes.py

```
...
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

@cart_blueprint.route('/add_item/<int:product_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_item(product_id):
    product = Product.query.get_or_404(product_id)
    cart_id = current_user.id
    cart = Cart.query.get(int(cart_id))
    cart_item = {}
    
    if any(product.id==cart_item.product_id for cart_item in cart.cart_items):
        cart_item = CartItem.query.filter(CartItem.product_id==product_id).\
                                    join(CartItem.cart).\
                                    filter(Cart.id==cart_id).first()
        flash(f'CartItem ID: {cart_item.id} already in cart')
...
```